# Creating a batch file that will email the size of a specific file

Tags: batch-file, task, sendmail, scheduler

I’m trying to create a batch file that will email me the size of a specific file on my local drive running Windows 7. This file will be continuously increasing in size. My intent is to have Task Scheduler run this batch file every hour so I can get hourly updates via email of the file’s size.

I've used sendEmail.exe in batch files in the past so hopefully that can be used for this as well.

If anyone can provide pointers on the command lines in the batch file to accomplish this task, it would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

to extract the size of a given file, use the ~z modifier, see `HELP CALL` and try this code

```
 @echo off
 sendmail --from me@somemail.com --to againme@domain.com --server smtp.mydomain.com --user memyself --password 1234 --subject "%1 %~z1"
```

call it `mailfilesize.bat`, save it somewhere in your PATH and invoke it from the command line with

```
mailfilesize "c:\documents and settings\user1408635\Application Data\filetomonitor.dat"
```

or from the task scheduler

```
schtasks /create /sc hourly /tn "Mail me the file size" /tr cmd /c mailfilesize.bat "c:\somefolder\filetomonitor.dat"
```

Comment: In the above command line, where do I include the name and path of the file that is being monitored? Also, does the batch file have to be located in the same directory as this file? Thanks.